# Distribution of QRs mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

$$ \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} (\frac{a}{p})a^n \equiv{0} \pmod{p} $$

I'm supposed to show this for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ with $n=1$, and for $ p\gt 5$ with $n=2$.

I already know the standard case of $n=0$. For $n \gt 0$ I assume a proof uses some information about the distribution of the QRs and NRs between $1$ and $p$ (because the higher numbers will have more weight in the sum), but I'm not sure what symmetry I should be looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do the $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ case.

Note that since $-1$ is a quadratic residue of $p$, we have 
$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p-a}{p}\right)$.

Note also that $p-a\equiv -a\pmod{p}$. So if $n=1$, or more generally if $n$ is odd,  then 
$$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)(p-a)^n+\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)a^n\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$$
The symmetry used is the left-right symmetry of the Legendre symbol in this case, and the fact that $(-a)^n=-a^n$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Hmm Why does $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p-a}{p}\right)$ only if -1 is a QR? In the n=2 case I guess I have to proceed similarly but somehow use that p-a + a = 0 mod p?

Comment: Because in general $(ab/p)=(a/p)(b/p)$ and in particular $(-a/p)=(-1/p)(a/p)$. So for primes of the form $4k+3$ we have $(-a/p)=-(a/p)$. Note that this is helpful for $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and  $n=2$  because $(-a)^2=a^2$ so we get cancellation just like in my answer but for a (somewhat) different reason.  Other ways of handling this kind of problem include the Euler Criterion, usually in combination with primitive roots.